# pandas: How do I split row into multiple columns?

Tags: pandas

my data in the text format is like this

```
[{"title": "System and Method for Maskless Direct Write Lithography", "lang": "en", "year": 2015, "references": ["354c172f-d877-4e60-a7eb-c1b1cf03ce4d", "76cf1064-b2b2-4245-940b-4e25dab9d41d"], "abstract": "A system and method for maskless direct write lithography are disclosed. The method includes receiving a plurality of pixels that represent an integrated circuit (IC) layout; identifying a first subset of the pixels that are suitable for a first compression method; and identifying a second subset of the pixels that are suitable for a second compression method. The method further includes compressing the first and second subset using the first and second compression method respectively, resulting in compressed data. The method further includes delivering the compressed data to a maskless direct writer for manufacturing a substrate. In embodiments, the first compression method uses a run-length encoding and the second compression method uses a dictionary-based encoding. Due to the hybrid compression method, the compressed data can be decompressed with a data rate expansion ratio sufficient for high-volume IC manufacturing.", "url": ["http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2016/0211117.html", "http://www.google.com/patents/US20160211117", "https://www.google.de/patents/US20160211117"], "id": "0000002e-c2f2-4e25-9341-60d39130ac7a", "fos": ["Electronic engineering", "Computer hardware", "Engineering", "Engineering drawing"]}]
```

i want to make like this

```
title                   lang      year     id

System and Method for    eng       2015   0000002e-c2f2-4e25-9341-60d39130ac7a
Maskless Direct 
Write Lithography
```

Comment: Please edit your question clarifying what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Save your JSON data as a string in the variable `data`

```
data = """
[{"title": "System and Method for Maskless Direct Write Lithography", "lang": "en", "year": 2015, "references": ["354c172f-d877-4e60-a7eb-c1b1cf03ce4d", "76cf1064-b2b2-4245-940b-4e25dab9d41d"], "abstract": "A system and method for maskless direct write lithography are disclosed. The method includes receiving a plurality of pixels that represent an integrated circuit (IC) layout; identifying a first subset of the pixels that are suitable for a first compression method; and identifying a second subset of the pixels that are suitable for a second compression method. The method further includes compressing the first and second subset using the first and second compression method respectively, resulting in compressed data. The method further includes delivering the compressed data to a maskless direct writer for manufacturing a substrate. In embodiments, the first compression method uses a run-length encoding and the second compression method uses a dictionary-based encoding. Due to the hybrid compression method, the compressed data can be decompressed with a data rate expansion ratio sufficient for high-volume IC manufacturing.", "url": ["http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2016/0211117.html", "http://www.google.com/patents/US20160211117", "https://www.google.de/patents/US20160211117"], "id": "0000002e-c2f2-4e25-9341-60d39130ac7a", "fos": ["Electronic engineering", "Computer hardware", "Engineering", "Engineering drawing"]}]
"""

df = pd.read_json(data, orient='records')
df[['title', 'lang', 'year']]
# Output:
#                                                      title lang  year
# 0  System and Method for Maskless Direct Write Lithography  en   2015
```

If your data is in a file you can read `data` from the file

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Comment: bro did not get the answer @user2314737

Comment: @KHURRAM check it now

Comment: my data is in excel

Comment: @KHURRAM please edit your question, it was not clear what the issue